# AS3 touch events lagging and causing unwanted right-click behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, touch, windows-10, flash, flashdevelop

This may be a long shot, but hopefully someone can help me with this.

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit on a Dell Inspiron laptop with a 10-touch-point touchscreen. I can get touch events to fire but they're not working the way I'd like in all cases.

A little preliminary info first. On a touchscreen Windows 10 PC, try touching and holding on the background. A transparent white square should tween from small to large, indicating that a right-click will occur if you release that touch. Instead of releasing, add a second touch somewhere else. The square should tween from large to small and disappear. This is normal behavior, and should happen anywhere that has right-click functionality.

Now open Google Chrome (I just updated to the new version 58 but I presume any version will do). Follow the steps from before and watch the square disappear. Now, while still holding a finger down, touch again somewhere else, and keep tapping. Notice the square tweening out over and over again in the same spot despite already having disappeared. If you release your original touch it remembers the point where that touch was released and continues to tween out the square in that spot. In Chrome you can use a two-finger tap to bring up the right-click menu, and I suspect this problem occurs anywhere that has two-finger tap right-click functionality. I suspect this is a Windows bug rather than a Chrome bug.

When I test my program in FlashDevelop this same problem occurs. The program responds pretty quickly when it's just one touch, but the events can lag considerably when there are multiple touches. I've tested in four environments with the following results:

- FlashDevelop: White square bug and lag
- Standalone Flash Player (projector): White square bug and no lag
- Google Chrome: No touch events firing at all
- Internet Explorer: No white square bug and no lag

So the ideal behavior seems to be what's happening in Internet Explorer, and I'd like that to happen everywhere. I'd like to know if there's a way to suppress the two-finger touch functionality or if there's some other way to fix this (I've already tried intercepting MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK events and it didn't work). Here's my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Kyle Delaney
     */
    [Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private static var _output_txt:TextField = new TextField();

        public function Main() 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            graphics.beginFill(0);

            graphics.drawRect( -5, -5, stage.stageWidth + 5, stage.stageHeight + 5);

            var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            tf.font = "Courier New";
            tf.size = "14";
            _output_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            _output_txt.wordWrap = true;
            _output_txt.width = stage.stageWidth /2;
            _output_txt.height = stage.stageHeight;
            _output_txt.selectable = false;
            _output_txt.mouseEnabled = false;
            _output_txt.background = true;
            _output_txt.alpha = 0.5;
            addChild(_output_txt);
            print("init()");

            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchBegin);
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
            //addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMove);
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, touchTap);
        }

        private function touchTap(e:TouchEvent):void 
        {
            print("touchTap() " + e.touchPointID);
        }

        private function touchMove(e:TouchEvent):void 
        {
            print("touchMove() " + e.touchPointID);
        }

        private function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void 
        {
            print("touchEnd() " + e.touchPointID);
        }

        private function touchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void 
        {
            print("touchBegin() " + e.touchPointID);
        }

        private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            print("mouseDown");
        }
        public static function print(str:String):void
        {
            if (_output_txt)
            {
                _output_txt.appendText(str + '\n');
                if (_output_txt.length > 10000) _output_txt.replaceText(0, 5000, "");
                _output_txt.scrollV = _output_txt.maxScrollV;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here's an upload of the swf: http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/8eb8b87e551f48db7e0e50c66d3178ff

Comment: This a moon-shot... I know AS3 has something about disabling right mouse clicks. Something like myDisplayObject.RIGHT_CLICK = false.  That's not it, but something along those lines. I wonder if doing that would affect the touch behavior?

Comment: a fast answer according to the question title, for a while, right click was disabled with e covering image (a transparent image) and it was just for browsers, and there was some communication between flash and javascript to handle events from outside

Comment: So are you talking about a transparent image not in the swf but on the webpage in front of the Flash Player?

Comment: @NealDavis, are you thinking of the way right-clicking can be disabled by just listening for RIGHT_CLICK events and then doing nothing in response? I've already tried that.

Comment: @KyleDelaney interesting. No that's not what I'm thinking of. If a simple google search didn't turn something up then I might be remembering something wrong. I'll see if I can dig something up on it later.